# Enable pan and zoom in Sencha chart on desktop PC

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I would like to pan the zoomed area in a sencha chart. Currently I'm only able to zoom in and out on the chart as you can see in this sample: [Sample Chart](http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.1.0/docs/Ext.chart.interactions.PanZoom.1/viewer.html). I'm using the app on a desktop PC.

At the moment there is no posibility to pan in the zoomed chart. I'm managed to get panning working but then zooming is not possible. Is there a way to get both? Is there a setting I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PanZoom-object has a proberty called *modeToggleButton*. Getter methode returns a button, which can be added to the UI. Clicking on it toggles between panning and zooming in the chart.